# How to hide form in Navigation Pane?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to restrict Datasheet viewing in the Navigation Pane shared with a Form.

How do I do that? I have already went to Design View and Property Sheet and changed the viewing, but I do not want it to show in the Navigation Pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent a form from being displayed in the Navigation Pane, you can set its hidden attribute (right-click the form in the Navigation Pane, then choose View Properties).  Then it will not be displayed unless the user has set Show Hidden Objects in Navigation Options.

Another approach is to rename the form so that its name starts with *"USys"*.  In that case, it will not be displayed in the Navigation Pane unless the user has set Show System Objects in Navigation Options.

If you later want to make the form visible in the Navigation Pane again, set both Show Hidden Objects and Show System Objects.  You may need to then close and reopen the Navigation Pane before it will actually be displayed.  Then locate it in the Navigation Pane, unset the hidden attribute or rename to remove *"USys"* ... depending on how you hid it in the first place.

Comment: Wow. Why didn't i try that? It worked! Thank you. So how do i unhide it?

Comment: You may have figured that out already, but I update the answer just in case.